# How to setup Root Page in Alchemy cms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alchemy-cms

After installation of Alchemy cms(Ruby), getting error as 'Root page not found.'. So how to create a Root page?

Answer (score 1):

Alchemy maintainer here :)

Did you setup your Database?

```
bin/rake alchemy:install
```

should've added `Alchemy::Seeder.seed!` into your app's `db/seeds.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

In `config.rb`, you use the `root 'controller#action'` to set root to whichever page you like. For example:

```
root 'home#main`
```

Alchemy [does this for you](https://github.com/AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms/blob/v3.1.1/config/routes.rb#L3), pointing at `pages#show`, which [loads your root page](https://github.com/AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms/blob/v3.1.1/app/controllers/alchemy/pages_controller.rb#L49) from the database.

Make sure you've set up Alchemy according to their [installation instructions](https://github.com/AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms/blob/v3.1.1/README.md#install-into-an-existing-rails-project), specifically running `rake alchemy:install`, which will seed your database with the root route.